# How can I clear my interval and stop repeated API calls?

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I have a form, where upon clicking start, I begin a series of API calls that call on the interval of 15 seconds. When I click stop, I would like to stop the API calls and clear the interval. For some reason, despite me hitting stop and my code saying it does enter the part of my code that clears the interval, the calls still keep going out.

```
app.post("/", (req,res) => {
    if(req.body.hasOwnProperty("start")) {
       var t = setInterval(function() {
           axios.post(url, data,config)
             .then(res => {
                 // do stuff
               })
              .then(res => {
                 // do stuff
               })
               .then(res => {
                  // about three thens after this
                })
              }, 30000)
           } else {
              console.log("Clearing Interval")
              clearInterval(t);
            }
});
```

Comment: Here, the request you get for `Start` and request you get for `Stop` are completely different. So the interval set for the `Start` request is not available when you get a another request for stopping i.e., `Stop` request. Also ideally if you've used `let t = setInterval(....` you would have got error, but since you've used `var` and because of hoisting when you are doing `clearInterval` for the `Stop` request it's not throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

the interval id should be stored in a global variable, what can be accessed from different client's requests.

And I guess, you just want to run a single action for the Interval.
 -> Should check existing intervalID before making a new

So it should be like this:

```
let intervalID;
app.post("/", (req,res) => {
  if(req.body.hasOwnProperty("start")) {
    if (!intervalID) {
      intervalID = setInterval(function() {
        axios.post(url, data,config)
            .then(res => {
              // do stuff
            })
            .then(res => {
              // do stuff
            })
            .then(res => {
              // about three thens after this
            })
      }, 30000)
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Clearing Interval")
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    intervalID = null;
  }
});
```

Comment: One problem that I could see over here is, consider `Start` request came from one source and `Stop` request came from another source then the timer will be stopped for all the sources.

Comment: yes, as I told, I guess him just want to run only one Interval. If he want to run multiple Interval, we have to use an array or an object to store all Intervals.
And when call api to stop, have to send an ID or key to server to know: what Interval do you want to stop?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I implemented it, and it still does not work.